# Downloading file from secure sharepoint server c#

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, networking

I'm trying to download a file from a Sharepoint server, however my code to supply credentials. Its security is the sort that you get a little WinForms pop up asking for login details like that of a network drive as opposed to a logon screen. 
This is what I am using

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("william.dunne", "legacy01");
    client.DownloadFile(URL, Filename);
}
```

Comment: You probably have to provide credentials in an App.config file (make one if there's none).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing the domain part of your username. Try supplying the domain to `NetworkCredentials` overloaded constructor.